# Pass scrollview delegate to child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cant seem to figure out how to set a scrollview's delegate as a viewcontroller within the scrollview.

```
ChildView *child = [[ChildView alloc] init];

_scrollview.delegate = child;
```

My child view controller is using the scrollview delegate:

```
@interface ChildView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

But it won't call scrollViewDidScroll;

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

Basically, I would like the scrollview offset of a scrollview to be passed to a view controller nested within it.

Comment: make sure 1. _scrollview has been initialized, 2. child has been retained as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can assign a property in Objective C.

1. **Assign** means to simply performs a variable assignment and sets one variable equal to another. You won't be able to use the variable if it goes out of scope. This is typically only used for C primitives.
2. **Weak** tells the compiler to keep a reference to the object as long as someone else points to it strongly.
3. **Strong** tells the compiler to keep a strong reference to the given object. This means that the object won't go out of scope until the object holding it goes out of scope.

As @Aaron pointed out, delegates properties are set using assign. This means that if the variable you are setting the delegate to goes out of scope, the reference becomes invalid. To remedy this, you have to keep a strong pointer to the object around so that it does not go out of scope.

To do this, create a property in your main view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ChildView * child;
```

Then, when you create the child view, set the property equal to it.

```
self.child = ChildView *child = [[ChildView alloc] init];
```

Now you can set the delegate and it won't go out of scope once your function terminates.

```
_scrollview.delegate = self.child;
```

Comment: One thing to note is that once all strong references to a weakly referenced property are released the property will be set to nil. Not so with assign (which used to be a fairly common way to setup delegates before weak)

Answer (score 1):

`child` is getting deallocated by the time the delegate method fires.

From UIScrollView.h:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;   // default nil. weak reference
```

This is a weak reference, so it won't be retained.  To fix it, create a `strong` @property in your main view controller, and set it to `child`.